# Incorrect returns from $.getJSON and node-async - server side node/express jsonp

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, node-async

I'm getting an odd error when using $.getJSON with node-async to a server running node/express with jsonp response.

I make two calls to the server using node-async iterating over an array but when all is done the second result has some properties which contain the values from the first.

The odd thing is that the server side response IS coming back - as one of the properties that came back is correct - but another property looks like it is overwritten on the second call by the property from the first.

On the server side, I've debugged it and checked the res.jsonp line which is returning the correct results, I've also checked it with some console logging server side.

Code below - TLDR results are as follows:

```
    //Expecting results to be:
    [
      {"series":1, options:{serverSays:"Here is series 1"},data: [a:1,b:2,c:3]},
      {"series":2, options:{serverSays:"Here is series 2"}, data: [x:9, y:8, z:7]}
    ]

    //Actual Results are
    [
      {"series":1, options:{serverSays:"Here is series 1"}, data: [a:1,b:2,c:3]},
      {"series":2, options:{serverSays:"Here is series 2"}, data: [a:1,b:2,c:3]}
    ]
```

Here's a simplified version of the code (with much junk taken out but logic remaining intact):

```
var series = [
  {id: 1},
  {id: 2}
]

var results = [];

//A function to get data from the server and return it
function getData(id, cb)
{
  var url = serverUrl + "/GetSomeData/" + id;

  $.getJSON(url)
  .done(function (serverResponse)
  {
    console.log("Response from server: ", serverResponse)
    cb({"series": id, options: serverResponse.options, data: serverResponse.data});
  }
}

//A function to iterate through the series using async.forEach    
function iterator(s, callback)
{
  getData(s.id, function(data)
  {
    //Use the data
    results.push(data);

    //Tell async we are done with this iteration
    callback() 
  });
}

function done(err)
{
    console.log("Finished");

    //Expecting results to be
    //[
    //  {"series":1, options:{serverSays:"You Requested Series 1"},data: [a:1,b:2,c:3]}, 
    //  {"series":2, options:{serverSays:"You Requested Series 2"}, data: [x:9, y:8, z:7]}
    //]

    //Actual Results are
    //[
    //  {"series":1, options:{serverSays:"You Requested Series 1"}, data: [a:1,b:2,c:3]}, 
    //  {"series":2, options:{serverSays:"You Requested Series 2"}, data: [a:1,b:2,c:3]}
    //]
}

async.eachSeries(series, iterator, done);
```

I've tried it with async series, async parallel and with the promise style getJSON and the callback style getJSON - all show the same error.

Could be my client side code or else maybe I'm doing something silly with the server side jsonp.

Server side, I build the data then go

```
return res.jsonp(output);
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I can see at least three separate variables, all called 'data'. The first thing I would do would be to find different names for them all.

Comment: Good point, i went through and changed them but no improvement, will keep trying.

Comment: In the done function you're potentIally swallowing an error that might be saying something. Please add the lines: if(err) console.log(err);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh. Looks like I was being caught out by an external function call breaking the chrome inspector horribly!!

I finally realised that the chrome console was not displaying valid data in the inspector, but if i JSON.stringify'd the object it displayed correctly.

E.g.

```
console.log("Server response is: ", serverResponse) //In the getJSON callback
```

Would give the tree view for the incorrect object which would look like this:

```
{"series":2, options:{serverSays:"Here is series 2"}, data: [a:1,b:2,c:3]} //Incorrect data property
```

But doing

```
console.log("Server response is: ", JSON.stringify(serverResponse))
```

Showed the correct JSON:

```
{"series":2, options:{serverSays:"Here is series 2"}, data: [x:9, y:8, z:7]} //Correct data property
```

--

The cause?  What I was doing with the data.  One of the "junk taken out" lines that i removed from the example was a call to a highcharts chart to set the series data - along the lines of

```
getData(s.id, function(data)
  {

    //THE OMITTED LINE
    chart.series[someSeries].setData(data.data);

    //Tell async to add data to the result list
    // and continue with the next iteration.
    callback(null, data); // err = null
});
```

This was tripping over a bug I had in the chart definition, but instead of failing gracefully it somehow broke the chrome inspector...!

I'm guessing  with the scope hell of node-async + $.getJSON + multiple functions + callbacks, this was the final straw.  Go Figure!

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit, I can't find any problem with your code. For the sake of exhausting all options, maybe you can try [async.map](https://github.com/caolan/async#maparr-iterator-callback)?

```js
var series = [
  {id: 1},
  {id: 2}
]

//A function to get data from the server and return it
function getData(id, cb)
{
  var url = serverUrl + "/GetSomeData/" + id;

  $.getJSON(url)
  .done(function (serverResponse)
  {
    console.log("Response from server: ", serverResponse);
    cb({"series": id, options: serverResponse.options, data: serverResponse.data});
  });
}

//A function to iterate through the series using async.forEach    
function iterator(s, callback)
{
  getData(s.id, function(data)
  {
    //Tell async to add data to the result list
    // and continue with the next iteration.
    callback(null, data); // err = null
  });
}

function done(err, result)
{
    console.log("Finished");
}

// Note that map doesn't perform the iterator in order, but the result list is in order.
async.map(series, iterator, done);
```

Have you tried checking the network tab of the developer tools to see the response from the server the browser received?

If the response is the same as the expected output, there is probably something missing from the picture here.

Comment: Good idea, gave async.map a try - but same outcome.  Checked the console immediately on the JSON responses and they are mixed up like described, after leaving the server correctly.  Next step is a re-write to take async out of the equation.